# How do I sync music to my Sony Walkman (Z Series) using Rhythmbox?

Tags: android, rhythmbox, music-player, mp3-player

I have recently purchased the new Walkman Z from Sony. I can transfer music by mounting it as a drive, but I would prefer to use Rhythmbox to do so. My other Android devices and MP3 players from the past have always just shown up without any tweaking.

Using Nautilus to transfer the files is possible but for some reason Nautilus still makes a trash folder on removable drives. Deleting the trash folder anew is really annoying to do every time I delete music from the device.

How can I use Rhythmbox to transfer and remove songs instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [really old article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/banshee-doesnt-show-android-fix) on how to work around the bug.

Creating an empty file called `.is_audio_player` in the root of the SD card  solves the problem, I can transfer and delete files from Rhythmbox now.